# Git clone from bitbucket server not works by https

Tags: git, macos, ssh, https, bitbucket-server

I am trying to clone repository from private bitbucket server to my os x computer.
It works well if i use `git clone ssh://git@repositoryname:0001/subfolder/reponame.git`, but when i try to call `git clone https://repositoryname/subfolder/reponame.git`, i get `fatal: remote error: Repository not found The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.`. Url seems to be right because i successfully cloned it using Sourcetree, but why i get this error doing git clone by console?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have a credential helper set when you clone through command-line (not SourceTree)

```
git config credential.helper
```

If you do, Try to clone it using the expected username, and see if a popup will ask you to enter the account password.

```
git clone https://<GitLabAccount>@repositoryname/subfolder/reponame.git
```